# Python - Open a link in new Chrome tab with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, webdriver

I would like to have a URL open in a new tab and closing itself rather than opening in front of the user as it currently stands. I want it to be a discrete as possible.

Here is the python code I have so far that works, but brings the window to the front:

```
def extract(self, id, pass):
    chrome_dir_path = '/Users/<user>/Downloads/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_dir_path)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('https://<URL>')
    username = driver.find_element_by_id('user')
    username.send_keys(USER)
    password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
    password.send_keys(PASS)
    driver.find_element_by_name('remUID').click()
    python_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')
    python_button.click()
```

Comment: if you want to be discrete then run with `headless` option and it will not display window.

Answer (score 0):

running headless resolved this issue.

Comment: Please give details about your solution. BTW, the comment "run with `headless` option..." looks better.